How can we update the length of each pointer in Sortedset Skip List insertion?
I’m implementing an insertion for Sortset SkipList. It was okay but now I need to make my get(index) to run in O(logn). It means that I have to combine Sortedset Skiplist and Skiplist list. So how can I update the length of pointers while maintaining the order of elements in the set ?
public boolean add(T x) {

        Node<T> u = sentinel;
        int r = h;
        int comp = 0;
        int j = -1; // Track index position as we traverse
        Node<T> w = new Node<>(x, pickHeight());

        // Traverse the levels from top down to find the correct position for `x`
        while (r >= 0) {
            while (u.next[r] != null && (comp = c.compare(u.next[r].x, x)) < 0) {

                u = u.next[r];
            }
            // Increment length on level `r` to account for the new node
            ;
            if (u.next[r] != null && comp == 0) return false; // Duplicate, exit early

            stack[r--] = u; // Store the node `u` in the stack for each level
        }

        // Update height if the new node `w` requires it
        while (h < w.height()) {
            stack[++h] = sentinel;
            sentinel.length[h] = n + 1;
        }

        j++; // `j` now represents the exact insertion index for `w`

        // Insert `w` and update lengths at each level
        for (int i = 0; i < w.next.length; i++) {

            w.next[i] = stack[i].next[i];
            stack[i].next[i] = w;

            // Calculate the lengths for `w` and `stack[i]`

        }

        n++; // Increment node count
        return true;
    }


Aren't all SkipLists sorted? What is your non-sorted SkipList sorting on? The index?

In each node of the skip list, you can also store the number of elements between this node and the next node at the same level (including the next node, but excluding the current node).
When adding an element, find all predecessors of the new value as per usual with skip list insertion. Keep track of the number of elements covered on each level while searching for the predecessors. For each level that the newly inserted value is present on, update the number of elements from the predecessor to the new node as the sum of all elements covered from the bottom level to the current level plus one. The new node takes on the count of remaining elements that were previously between the predecessor and the next node. For predecessors not on a level not containing the new value, simply increment its number of elements to the next node by one.
When deleting a node, for each predecessor, add one less than the count of elements covered between the node to be deleted and its next node to the predecessor (if the node to be deleted does not exist on this level, this count is zero).
To implement finding by rank/index, use a similar procedure to searching for a key, but instead of comparing keys, maintain the current count of elements passed by summing the count of elements between adjacent nodes on levels when moving forward.
